# Loss of precision when casting float to double

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, double, precision

I guess I'm hitting a precision issue with my c++ program. And I don't understand why I'm getting different results in my values.

`res` equals to `1321.0000001192093` if I write:

```
float sy = -0.207010582f;
double res = -1512.*((double)sy - (2. / 3.));
```

but res2 equals to `1320.9999999839999` if I write:

```
double res2 = -1512.*(-0.207010582 - (2. / 3.));
```

Why even syd is different from syd2 when I write this:

```
double syd  = -0.207010582f;
double syd2 = -0.207010582000000000;
```

Can somebody give me a hand, to cast my float into a double properly and to understand what's going on ?

Comment: `-0.207010582f` is a float so obviously it's less precise than `-0.207010582` which is a double. Casting like `(double)sy` is correct although not in a C++ way (which should be `static_cast<double>(sy)`. But upcasting like doesn't magically give you the precision you lost by using float in the first place. To avoid that you must use double right from the beginning

Comment: Sy is given by an external dll I cannot change its type.  I don't get why casting this float into double change it's value basicaly.

Comment: and if you want even higher degree of precision, then you should try gmpxx

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that cast isn't needed. Since the type of `2. / 3.` is `double`, the value of `sy` will be converted to `double` to match. The calculation is the same with or without the cast.

Answer (score 2):

`-0.207010582f` is a decimal floating-point literal. But your computer doesn't use decimal floating point, it uses binary floating point. So the value of that literal will be rounded to `float` precision.

Similarly, `-0.207010582` is rounded to `double` precision. While that's closer, it still is not equal to `-0.207010582` decimal.

Since `double` has more precision than `float`, you will **not** lose precision by casting from `float` to `double`. Any rounding will have happened earlier.

Comment: The internal floating point representation of  -0.207010582f is not stricly equal to the literal -0.207010582000000000000 ?

Comment: @cyrilc: Correct. It would be `-0.20701058208942413330078125`, if expressed in decimal, or `10111110010100111111101010010101` in bits.

Answer (score 2):

**Single-Precision**

As others have said, `float sy = -0.207010582f;` initializes a single-precision (32-bit) floating point variable from a single-precision floating point literal.

This will be treated (in storage and calculations) as the nearest representable number in that format.  This number is `-0.20701058208942413330078125`

You code is effectively then `float sy = -0.20701058208942413330078125;`

You can confirm that this is the nearest representable value by looking at the adjacent single-precision floating point numbers.

```
-0.20701059699058532714843750   // std::nextafter( sy, std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest() )
-0.20701058208942413330078125   // sy
-0.20701056718826293945312500   // std::nextafter( sy, std::numeric_limits<float>::max() )
```

**Double-Precision**

Exactly the same occurs with double-precision floating point numbers, it's just their increased resolution means the differences are small.
e.g `double dy = -0.207010582;` actually represents the value `0.20701058199999999853702092877938412129878997802734375`

Similarly, the adjacent values that can be represented are -

```
-0.2070105820000000262925965444082976318895816802978515625  // std::nextafter( dy, std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest() )
-0.2070105819999999985370209287793841212987899780273437500  // dy
-0.2070105819999999707814453131504706107079982757568359375  // std::nextafter( dy, std::numeric_limits<double>::max() )
```

**Single to Double Conversion**

All single precision floating point values are exactly representable in double-precision.  Hence, nothing is lost in conversions from single to double precision.

---

All the above assumes IEEE754 floating-point representation.